# how to cancel window.print(); on click on the Print button, Print pop up but no print action

Tags: javascript, printing, onclicklistener, actionlistener, cancellation

I want to have the window.print() pop up but when User clicks on Print button, it is not windows print but onclick or window.onbeforeprint I wish to trigger my own personalised print function. 
As such, on click Print, I need to cancel the print action and trigger my personalised() function.

Please help how to cancel window.print(); on click on the Print button

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply using the `preventDefault()`.

What `Event.preventDefault()` does is

> The Event interface's **preventDefault()** method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its event listeners calls stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation(), either of which terminates propagation at once.

You can read more at [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) from MDN Web Docs

From your post, it looks like you are not referencing any JavaScript libraries (such as jQuery)... so a straight up JavaScript approach would be:

```
document.querySelector("#printLink").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //your printing related window code etc.
}, false);
```

If, however, you are using a JavaScript library and it happens to be jQuery, then the following will be what you are looking for--

```
jQuery("#printLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your printing related window code etc.
});
```

[jQuery event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

In either case, your print link would look like:

```
<a id="printLink" ...></a>
```

(Notice the `ID` attribute in the anchor element)

Comment: But how to I capture Event from window.print(); when onclick Print button and not onclick Cancel button ?

Comment: There is no printLink here. it is the standard window.print();

Comment: @Pax so hold on... which scenario are you looking for? Scenario A: User clicks on *Print button/link* on your page and you intercept that and show your custom print function? or Scenario B: User clicks on *Print button/link* on your page, the `system` print dialog opens and **then** when the user clicks print again, you want to intercept that?

Comment: Scenario B: By system print dialog opens, I mean window.print();  in JavaScript.